# can you determine location of the tap/click within an image when using .gesture(DragGesture) while still using the coordinateSpace: .global?

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop

When I use this method to drag an image, I am targeting clear image overlays in the view based on an array of the empty frames. I need to adjust the "location" value based on where the image was tapped/clicked on because the location is based on the upper left corner of the image, regardless of where in the image the user taps/clicks. so I need an offset from the click location to the upper left corner of the image.

```
.gesture(
        DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged {
                self.dragAmount = CGSize(width: $0.translation.width, height: -$0.translation.height)
                self.dragState = self.onChanged?($0.location, piece.square) ?? .unknown
            }
            .onEnded {
                if self.dragState == .good {
                    self.onEnded?($0.location, piece.square)
                }
                self.dragAmount = .zero
            }
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.